# GitHub Pages - How to prevent conversion of file names to *.html in links

Tags: github, jekyll

I am using GitHub Pages to create a static web site.
It does a great job processing links such that `file1.md` becomes `file1.html` in the rendered output:

For example:

```
[Link text](https://github.com/some-repo/some-file.md)
```

in the Markdown source becomes this when rendered using GitHub Pages:

```
<a href="https://github.com/some-repo/some-file.html">Link text</a>
```

Can I override this conversion somehow and link to an actual md file? In other words, output that looks like this:

```
<a href="http://https://github.com/some-repo/some-file.md">Link text</a>
```

Thanks for any insight you can lend!

I have tried embedding the HTML `<a>` element in the source, but the conversion still happens.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the path to a particular page (`.md` file) using the `page.path` variable.

That path is relative to the branch directory in your repo.

So you can link to the `.md` source file using this URL:

```
https://github.com/YourUsername/YourRepo/blob/your-branch/{{ page.path }}
```

For my purposes, I use this URL:

```
https://github.com/KevinWorkman/HappyCoding/blob/gh-pages/{{ page.path }}
```

If you already know the path, then you can use that directly instead of using the `page.path` variable:

```
https://github.com/YourUsername/YourRepo/blob/your-branch/some/path/some-file.md
```