# Hyperlinking to a Page via its Path with Jekyll (GitHub Pages)

Tags: html, jekyll, github-pages

I have a page called `en.md` and another page called `ko.md` in a directory. Both files have custom-set permalinks, so `en.md` and `ko.md` respectively are not a part of the page URL. Regardless of this setting, to move from `en.md` to `ko.md` in normal HTML, all I would need to do is this :

```
<a href="ko.md">Move to File KO</a>
```

However, this doesn't seem to work in Jekyll; this link sends me straight to URL `.../ko.md`, where there is no file (because of that permalink setting), rendering my link unusable. Is there a way to link to a specific **file** instead of just permalinks in Jekyll-processed HTML? Thank you!

Comment: Does this post help you?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57367689/github-pages-how-to-prevent-conversion-of-file-names-to-html-in-links

Comment: It's a fine start, but how would I be able to use this when I need to move to a different page? `page.path` doesn't seem like a viable option. Thanks for the link though - I'll try to extend on this idea and leave my progress as an answer if successful :)

Comment: After you use `jekyll` to build your source code (e.g. `jekyll build`, `jekyll serve`), have you taken a look in your `_site` folder to see what files are available for you to link?  More info on `_site` direcotry https://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/.  Is your question, "How can I have `jekyll` convert my `*.md` file to an `*html`, but still keep the `*.md` file too?  `jekyll` assumes that if it needs to process a `*.md` file, the original `*.md` file is not packaged during `jekyll build`.

Comment: Oh I didn't know the `.md`s were converted to `.html`s! I really need to read those docs much more thoroughly - that explains why the `.md`s weren't recognised as files. Thank you!

Comment: If you are looking for a way to access the raw markdown file through `jekyll`, see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159286/how-can-i-access-un-rendered-markdown-content-in-jekyll-with-liquid-tags